# maftir 7th day of Pesach

Tags: passover, minor-katan-child, chasidut-hasidism, chabad, maftir

The *Luach Kolel Chabad* says a minor can't be *maftir* on the seventh day of *Pesach*. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we want to show extra honor to the Song of David recited as the haftarah, and have an adult read it (Magen Avraham 282:12, cited in Shulchan Aruch Harav [284:8](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh2/1/284/8.htm)).

Comment: Thank you! And that led me to find that the _Mishna B'rura_ also cites the _MA l'halacha_, at 282:23.